# Inno Setup: Don't install if file exists

Tags: automation, inno-setup

My goal is to prevent Inno Setup from installing my program if it already exists (my program includes more files besides the .exe i'm checking, this is just a way to quickly "decide" whether to install or not). I'm using the /verysilent parameter.

This is what i have so far:

```
[Code]
function IsMyProgramInstalled: boolean;
begin
  result := FileExists('C:\MyProgramFolder\myprogram.exe');
end;

function InitializeSetup: boolean;
begin
  result := IsMyProgramInstalled;
  if result then
    MsgBox('Some custom message', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

The problem is that after the message the setup continues. I know i need to return a false value for the installer to stop, but i don't know how to do it. Anyone knows how can i achieve this? If it's not possible this way is there a alternative? Unfortunately i know nothing about Pascal scripting. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Tlama solution is correct:

```
[Code]
function IsMyProgramInstalled: boolean;
begin
  result := FileExists('C:\MyProgramFolder\MyProgram.exe');
end;

function InitializeSetup: boolean;
begin
  result := not IsMyProgramInstalled;
  if not result then
    MsgBox('Some custom message', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: You need to write `Result := not IsMyProgramInstalled;` (`not` is the inverter you were looking for), because that `Result` boolean value determines whether the setup will run (read it as, run the setup if my program is `not` installed). Similar applies probably also to the next condition `if not Result then...` (if the setup will `not` run, then...).

Comment: TLama, is it possible launch "C:\MyProgramFolder\myprogram.exe" instead of displaying the MsgBox? Thanks

Comment: Yes, check the [`Exec`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) function.

Comment: @TLama It's working now, i just used the example you linked, and changed the constant to point to MyProgram.exe location (`'{drive:C:}\MyProgramFolder\MyProgram.exe'`). Thanks!